# Grep search for text in an ISO-8859-1 encoded file

Tags: linux, grep, character-encoding

I'm attempting to use `grep` to search for text patterns from an ISO-8859-1 encoded file: [wordsList](https://github.com/jfoclpf/words-pt)

When I execute a search, all of the matches are returned, but the accented characters are stripped. For example, if I want to search of all the words ending in `-ese`:

```
$ LC_ALL=pt_PT.ISO-8859-1  grep -a ese\$  wordsList
```

This results in 58 matches. One of the matches is the word `hipótese`, but when printed out appears as `hiptese` (missing the `ó` character).  How can I prevent the `grep` output from stripping the accented characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How can I prevent the `grep` output from stripping the accented characters?

`grep` itself does not strip accented characters, it outputs matching lines as they are in the input file. It's your terminal (terminal emulator) that doesn't interpret accented characters encoded as ISO-8859-1 as anything it should *display* as accented characters.

Your terminal most likely expects UTF-8. The rest of this answer assumes the terminal does expect UTF-8 and the locale is `something.UTF-8` (e.g. `pt_PT.UTF-8`). It should be so in many modern Unix-like systems by default, certainly in Linux.

Possible solutions:

- You may be able to configure your terminal emulator to ISO-8859-1, run the command and reconfigure back to UTF-8. (e.g. in `konsole` select from the menu: `View`, `Set Encoding`; and so on). I wouldn't call this the right way though.
- Alternatively convert the output of `grep` to UTF-8 on the fly:

  ```
  LC_ALL=pt_PT.ISO-8859-1 grep -a ese\$ wordsList | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8
  ```
- If you plan to work with the file a lot, convert the content to UTF-8*:

  ```
  <wordsList iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 >wordsList-utf8
  ```

  Then work with the new file without tricks, e.g.:

  ```
  grep ese\$ wordsList-utf8
  ```

  Now you can even grep for accented characters in a straightforward way, e.g.:

  ```
  grep ó wordsList-utf8
  ```

  In general [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) may be a problem; but here, since the file is a conversion from ISO-8859-1, I expect consistency: every `ó` shall be [U+00F3](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00F3) (`0xC3B3` in UTF-8, the above `grep` will find it), not [U+006F](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+006F) followed by [U+0301](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0301) (`0x6FCC81` in UTF-8, the above `grep` would not find it); similarly for other accented characters.

---

* I notice you used `grep -a`, as if you needed `grep` to treat binary files like text. If your `wordsList` is truly non-text, converting the whole of it to UTF-8 may fail or give you mangled non-text parts. Since you did not link to a single specific file, I cannot investigate further without guessing. I guess you meant the file linked under "just the file", i.e. the file one can extract from [wordsList.zip](https://github.com/jfoclpf/words-pt/blob/master/wordsList.zip?raw=true). With this particular file I do not need `-a` for `grep`, if only I tell `grep` to use the right encoding (this is what `LC_ALL=pt_PT.ISO-8859-1` does).

Comment: Indeed the filename should have been `wordsList` and I've update my original post. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm using the kitty terminal, but now that I know it's related to the terminal (not grep itself), I know where to focus my efforts.

One difference from your comment. Regardless of which terminal I'm using (kitty, gnome, xfce4), It's necessary for me to specify the `-a` option for grep, otherwise it skips any words with accented characters.

Comment: @JeffBauer For me `grep` "thinks" the file is binary when working in UTF-8; but with `LC_ALL=pt_PT.ISO-8859-1` it does not, `-a` is not needed. My `grep` is GNU `grep` 3.8.